# Convert two character ASCII string to DOUBLE in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I want to convert the string "ME" into the double 25933 in VBS
I am trying the following aproach with no luck

```
value = AscB(ASCII("M")) *2^8
value = value + AscB(ASCII("E"))
value = CDbl(value)
```

This conversion is for an HMI display that displays double words as strings. 25933 gives me "ME". Dont let me misguide you, I am not sure if this is supposed to be a "double" I am just trying to get 25933 from "ME", like in an ideal world(pseudo code) Cdouble(CByte("M")+CByte("E")).

Comment: `Asc("M")` = 77 = 0x4D, `Asc("E")` = 69 = 0x45, `Asc("e")` = 101 = 0x65. 25933 = 0x654D, so if I get your logic right it corresponds to "Me" (with lowercase "e"), whereas "ME" (all uppercase) corresponds to 0x454D = 17741.

Comment: @Helen, good info. There also appears to be an endian-ness issue. The "e" should be shifted to the left, not the "M".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get the logic right, your example is incorrect.

```
Asc("M") = 77  = 0x4D
Asc("E") = 69  = 0x45
Asc("e") = 101 = 0x65
```

That is, the numeric representation of "ME" is 17741 (0x454D), whereas 25933 (0x654D) corresponds to "Me".

As for your code, it uses the first character for the upper byte and the second character for the lower byte, but it seems it should be vice versa:

```
WScript.Echo Str2Num("Me") ' 25933
WScript.Echo Str2Num("ME") ' 17741

Function Str2Num(Str)
  ch1 = Left(Str, 1)
  ch2 = Mid(Str, 2, 1)
  Str2Num = CDbl(Asc(ch2) * 256  + Asc(ch1))
End Function
```

Comment: Helen, I think there is a mistake in function code. The last line should read `Str2Num = `, not `Str2Dbl = `.